# Return a ranking from multiple table with mySQL

Tags: mysql

Here my table structure:

**___Lang:**

```
|--------|------------|
| LAN_Id | LAN_En     |
|--------|------------|
| DI     | Direct     |
| WE     | Web        |
| OT     | Other      |
|--------|------------|
```

**___Segmentations:**

```
|--------|------------|
| SEG_Id | SEG_Code   |
|--------|------------|
| 1      | DI         |
| 2      | WE         |
| 3      | OT         |
|--------|------------|
```

**___Bookings:**

```
|--------|------------------|
| BOO_Id | BOO_Segmentation |
|--------|------------------|
| 1      | 1                |
| 2      | 1                |
| 3      | 2                |
|--------|------------------|
```

**___BillableDatas:**

```
|--------|---------------|------------|------------|
| BIL_Id | BIL_BookingId | BIL_Date   | BIL_Item   |
|--------|---------------|------------|------------|
| 1      | 1             | 2017-02-21 | Night      |
| 2      | 1             | 2017-02-22 | Night      |
| 3      | 1             | 2017-02-23 | Night      |
| 4      | 1             | 2017-02-24 | Night      |
| 5      | 2             | 2017-02-25 | Night      |
| 6      | 2             | 2017-02-26 | Night      |
| 7      | 3             | 2017-02-28 | Night      |
| 8      | 3             | 2017-03-01 | Night      |
| 9      | 3             | 2017-03-02 | Night      |
| 10     | 3             | 2017-03-03 | Night      |
|--------|---------------|------------|------------|
```

---

I would like to know the most popular segmentation for a range of date.

The desired result should be this one for the following date range :

**Form 2017-02-01 to 2017-02-28 inclusive**

```
|------------|------------|------------|--------------|------------|
| ROO_Name   | Night_Nb   | Percentage | Booking_Nb   | Percentage |
|------------|------------|------------|--------------|------------|
| Direct     | 6          | 85.71      | 2            | 66.66      |
| Website    | 1          | 14.28      | 1            | 33.33      |
| Other      | 0          | 0          | 0            | 0          |
|------------|------------|------------|--------------|------------|
```

---

What I already tried:

```
SELECT r.SEG_Id
     , Sum(CASE WHEN BOO_Id IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) Night_Nb
     , Concat(
         Format(
           Sum(CASE WHEN BOO_Id IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) 
           / TotalBookings 
           * 100
         , 0) ) AS PercentageTotal
  FROM (  ___Segmentations r LEFT JOIN ___Bookings b ON r.SEG_Id = b.BOO_Segmentation
       ) INNER JOIN (SELECT BOO_HotelId
                          , Count(*) AS TotalBookings
                       FROM ___Bookings 
                      GROUP BY BOO_HotelId
                    ) AS TotalHotelBookings 
                 ON r.SEG_HotelId = TotalHotelBookings.BOO_HotelId
 WHERE r.SEG_HotelId = :hotel_id
 GROUP BY r.SEG_Id
 ORDER BY NumBookings DESC
```

But it doesn't work actually.

Could anyone help me with this please ?

You could use the SQL Fiddle:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1aa10a

Comment: The percentage column values in the desired output seem wrong (should be first 66%?)

Comment: Right, I've updated the question. Thanks.

Comment: You have `hotelid` in your query, but it is not in your table structure.

Comment: `hotel_id` refer to a PDO `$query->execute(array(...`

Comment: Can you exaplain meaning of columns in desired output (Night_NB, Booking_NB)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest we build the query incrementally, step by step. Verify that the query results are as we expect at each step. When something "doesn't work", backup a step.

We want to return three rows, one for each row in `___Segmentations`, for a specific `hotelid`

```
 SELECT r.seg_id
      , r.seg_text
   FROM ___Segmentations r
  WHERE r.seg_hotelid = :hotel_id
  ORDER BY r.seg_id
```

Add the outer join to `__Bookings`

```
 SELECT r.seg_id
      , r.seg_text
      , b.boo_id
   FROM ___Segmentations r
   LEFT
   JOIN ___Bookings b
     ON b.boo_segmentation = r.seg_id
  WHERE r.seg_hotelid = :hotel_id
  ORDER
     BY r.seg_id
      , b.boo_id
```

Add the outer join to `___BillableDatas`

```
 SELECT r.seg_id
      , r.seg_text
      , b.boo_id
      , d.bil_id
   FROM ___Segmentations r
   LEFT
   JOIN ___Bookings b
     ON b.boo_segmentation = r.seg_id
   LEFT
   JOIN `___BillableDatas` d
     ON d.bil_bookingid = b.boo_id
  WHERE r.seg_hotelid = :hotel_id
  ORDER
     BY r.seg_id
      , b.boo_id
      , d.bil_id
```

If that's the rows we're interested in, we can work on aggregation.

```
 SELECT r.seg_id
      , r.seg_text
      , COUNT(DISTINCT b.boo_id) AS cnt_bookings
      , COUNT(DISTINCT d.bil_id) AS cnt_billable
   FROM ___Segmentations r
   LEFT
   JOIN ___Bookings b
     ON b.boo_segmentation = r.seg_id
   LEFT
   JOIN `___BillableDatas` d
     ON d.bil_bookingid = b.boo_id
  WHERE r.seg_hotelid = :hotel_id
  GROUP
     BY r.seg_id
      , r.seg_text
  ORDER
     BY r.seg_text
```

Now to get the aggregation with the "total".

The approach I would take would be to make "copies" of the rows, using a CROSS JOIN operation.  We can do the join to the rows returned by the very first query we wrote, referenced as an inline view. (Aliased as `q` below.)

If we have a complete set of rows, repeated for each `seg_id/seg_text` (that first query we wrote), we can use conditional aggregation.

That last query we wrote (just above) is an inline view in the query below, aliased as `c`.

SUM of `cnt_bookings` from all the rows is the total.

For the individual counts, we can include only the rows that have a matching `seg_id`, a total of that subset.

```
 SELECT q.seg_id
      , q.seg_text
      , SUM(IF(c.seg_id=q.seg_id,c.cnt_bookings,0))  AS cnt_bookings
      , SUM(c.cnt_bookings)                          AS tot_bookings
      , SUM(IF(c.seg_id=q.seg_id,c.cnt_billable,0))  AS cnt_billable
      , SUM(c.cnt_billable)                          AS tot_billable
   FROM ( SELECT t.seg_id
               , t.seg_text
            FROM ___Segmentations t
           WHERE t.seg_hotelid = :hotel_id_1
           ORDER BY t.seg_id
        ) q
  CROSS
   JOIN ( SELECT r.seg_id
               , COUNT(DISTINCT b.boo_id) AS cnt_bookings
               , COUNT(DISTINCT d.bil_id) AS cnt_billable
            FROM ___Segmentations r
            LEFT
            JOIN ___Bookings b
              ON b.boo_segmentation = r.seg_id
            LEFT
            JOIN `___BillableDatas` d
              ON d.bil_bookingid = b.boo_id
           WHERE r.seg_hotelid = :hotel_id
           GROUP
              BY r.seg_id
        ) c
  GROUP
     BY q.seg_id
      , q.seg_text
  ORDER
     BY q.seg_text
```

In the `SELECT` list, we can do the division to get the percentage: `cnt_bookings * 100.0  / tot_bookings`

e.g.

```
 SELECT q.seg_id
      , q.seg_text

      , SUM(IF(c.seg_id=q.seg_id,c.cnt_bookings,0))  AS cnt_bookings
      , SUM(c.cnt_bookings)                          AS tot_bookings
      , SUM(IF(c.seg_id=q.seg_id,c.cnt_bookings,0))
        * 100.0 / SUM(c.cnt_bookings)                AS pct_bookings

      , SUM(IF(c.seg_id=q.seg_id,c.cnt_billable,0))  AS cnt_billable
      , SUM(c.cnt_billable)                          AS tot_billable
      , SUM(IF(c.seg_id=q.seg_id,c.cnt_billable,0))
        * 100.0 / SUM(c.cnt_billable)                AS pct_billable
```

Modify the ORDER BY clause to return the rows in the order you want

Remove from the `SELECT` list the expressions that return `tot_bookings` and `tot_billable`.

**EDIT**

I think I missed the date critera. We can make the outer joins into inner joins, and replace the CROSS JOIN with a LEFT JOIN. We have potential to return NULL values for `cnt_bookings` and `cnt_billable`, we can wrap those in IFNULL() or COALESCE() function to replace NULL with zero.

```
 SELECT q.seg_id
      , q.seg_text

      , SUM(IF(c.seg_id=q.seg_id,c.cnt_bookings,0))  AS cnt_bookings
      , SUM(c.cnt_bookings)                          AS tot_bookings
      , SUM(IF(c.seg_id=q.seg_id,c.cnt_bookings,0))
        * 100.0 / SUM(c.cnt_bookings)                AS pct_bookings

      , SUM(IF(c.seg_id=q.seg_id,c.cnt_billable,0))  AS cnt_billable
      , SUM(c.cnt_billable)                          AS tot_billable
      , SUM(IF(c.seg_id=q.seg_id,c.cnt_billable,0))
        * 100.0 / SUM(c.cnt_billable)                AS pct_billable

   FROM ( SELECT t.seg_id
               , t.seg_text
            FROM ___Segmentations t
           WHERE t.seg_hotelid = :hotel_id_1
           ORDER BY t.seg_id
        ) q
   LEFT
   JOIN ( SELECT r.seg_id
               , COUNT(DISTINCT b.boo_id) AS cnt_bookings
               , COUNT(DISTINCT d.bil_id) AS cnt_billable
            FROM ___Segmentations r
            JOIN ___Bookings b
              ON b.boo_segmentation = r.seg_id
            JOIN `___BillableDatas` d
              ON d.bil_bookingid = b.boo_id
             AND d.bil_date BETWEEN '2017-02-21' AND '2017-02-28'
           WHERE r.seg_hotelid = :hotel_id
           GROUP
              BY r.seg_id
        ) c
     ON 1=1   
  GROUP
     BY q.seg_id
      , q.seg_text
  ORDER
     BY q.seg_text
```

Comment: I think I missed the date condition. We backup to where that should be added, and then move forward again.  We can do inner joins rather than LEFT joins, and replace the CROSS JOIN with a LEFT JOIN, and then use an IFNULL function around the SUM() aggregates.

Comment: Wow. Wonderful answer. Your comments and approach help me a lot undressing the processus. One thing, I've juste update the question by adding a new table for the translation. Sorry. I also changed the `SEG_Text`to `SEG_Code`. Do you think you can update your code please? I will take your answer. Hope I can change my vote. Thanks a lot @spencer7593.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure 100% how the `hotelId` column comes into play here, you didn't describe it in the question, but try this:

```
SELECT aaa.SEG_Text, aaa.Night_NB, aaa.Night_NB / totals.total_nights * 100, aaa.Booking_Nb , aaa.Booking_Nb / totals.total_bookings * 100 FROM (
SELECT s.SEG_Text, COUNT(DISTINCT d.BIL_Id) AS `Night_Nb`, COUNT(DISTINCT b.BOO_Id) AS `Booking_Nb` FROM ___Segmentations s 
    LEFT JOIN ___Bookings b ON s.SEG_Id = b.BOO_Segmentation 
    LEFT JOIN ___BillableDatas d ON d.BIL_BookingId = b.BOO_Id AND d.BIL_Date BETWEEN '2017-02-01' AND '2017-02-28'         
    GROUP BY s.SEG_Id ) AS `aaa` 

 , ( SELECT COUNT(*) AS `total_nights`, COUNT(DISTINCT BIL_BookingId) `total_bookings` FROM ___BillableDatas WHERE BIL_Date BETWEEN '2017-02-01' AND '2017-02-28') AS totals
```

It basically does the same stuff you did, but uses `SELECT(DISTINCT ...)` and thus is easier to understand, debug, and I think will also run faster.
For me it returns correct results.

Answer (score 0):

The challenge here seems to be to avoid doing almost the same query twice (repeating the date condition) in order to calculate the two percentages.

You could use the `with rollup` modifier to generate the total counts which you need to calculate those percentages. You could then capture these totals in variables, and use them in a wrapping query as divisors. Finally, the outer query's `where` clause would eliminate the `rollup` record, as it has served its purpose:

```
select   seg_text 
       , night_nb 
       , 100*night_nb/@sum_night_nb as night_pct
       , booking_nb 
       , 100*booking_nb/@sum_booking_nb as booking_pct
from     (
         select     seg_text
                  , @sum_night_nb := count(bil_id) night_nb
                  , @sum_booking_nb := count(distinct bil_bookingid) booking_nb
         from       ___segmentations seg 
         left join  (___bookings boo
         inner join ___billabledatas bil
                 on bil_bookingid = boo_id
                and bil_hotelid = boo_hotelid)
                 on seg_id = boo_segmentation 
                and seg_hotelid = boo_hotelid
                and bil_date between '2017-02-01' and '2017-02-28'
         where      seg_hotelid = 'AAA00'
         group by   seg_text with rollup
         ) base
where    seg_text is not null        
order by night_nb desc
```

See [this sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1aa10a/11)

Comment: I see you unaccepted this answer. No problem for me, but could you tell me what the issue is?

Comment: I liked the step by step proposed by @spencer7593.

Comment: Yes, that is indeed nice. I do notice however his solution needs 3 `select` statements, while it can be done more efficiently with 2.