# mySQL query that don't return the same result each time

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm facing a curious problem with a query.

The query is working very well and returns me the desired output but sometimes it returns me others datas.

In SQL Fiddle all is working well:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/64499b

But if you try that in phpMyAdmin (vers 4.0.10.14) and refresh the query like 20 times,

sometimes, the output is the right one (like in SQL Fiddle):

[image: Good datas]

and sometimes it's the wrong datas.

[image: Bad datas]

I try with a new DB with no datas in it.

Any reason why it's happen please ?

I do not have any solutions...

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Variables and `group by` don't work well together in MySQL.

Comment: @GordonLinoff, so it could be the reason why sometimes the result returns is not the same? A query work or not. That's strange in this case.

Comment: @qatari: The MySQL Reference Manual states "As a general rule, other than in SET statements, you should never assign a value to a user variable and read the value within the same statement." It goes on to say, "the order of evaluation for expressions involving user variables is undefined.", and that "You might get the results you expect, but this is not guaranteed."   https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/user-variables.html

Comment: I don't see why a user defined variable would be used. I'm also not understanding why the inline view includes "with rollup", when the extra row produced is going to be excluded (by the condition in the WHERE clause of the outer query.) I also pity the future reader of this SQL. None of the column references are qualified (with a table name or alias), so that guy is going to have to slog through the definition of every referenced table, looking for a column name that matches. (And when someone adds a column with the same name to a different table, that statement is going to have to be fixed.)

Comment: @spencer7593: hum... You probably pointed a good point. Any idea on how I can update the query without assigning a value to a user variable ? For the query, I ask help on SO few days ago here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42726428/return-a-ranking-from-multiple-table-with-mysql/42727873#42727873.